# Conditionally transposing from one column to rows

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, transpose, worksheet-function

I'm working with data in a spreadsheet that's one column, comments from news articles that couldn't be scraped with the browser extension I use because they use Disqus, which stores comments in an iframe. [Here's an example article](https://www.mercurynews.com/2017/08/15/google-protest-saturday-just-the-start-as-far-right-targets-bay-area/).

it usually looks something like:

```
     A
1 [username]
2 [date posted]
3 [Comment]
4 [# of likes]
5 [Extraneous dash]
6 [username]
7 [date posted]
8 [Comment]
9 [# of likes]
10 [Extraneous dash]
```

I'm trying to convert this into

```
      A           B           C         D             
1 username   date posted   comment  # of likes  
2 username   date posted   comment  # of likes
```

If all comments were like this, it'd be a piece of cake, as I could use this formula I found elsewhere:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,ROW(A1)*5-5+COLUMN(A1))
```

But every new paragraph of a person's comment is a new row. And some people's comments aren't liked, such that some people's comments are

```
     A
1 [username]
2 [date posted]
3 [Comment para 1]
4 [Comment para 2]
5 [Comment para 3]
6 [Comment para 4]
7 [Extraneous dash]
```

How do I join the paragraphs into one cell and then rotate into the above format?

I've been looking at textjoin, concat, and index functions, but I'm not sure how to put it together, if indeed it's possible. I was also thinking it might require using the dashes or putting in numbers where the likes are? I just learned what a CSE formula is if it gives you an idea of where I'm at.

Comment: So, you as a human being with reading skills and some intelligence can tell if a row is a comment paragraph or not. Because you read the text and understand the context. Excel cannot do the reading and interpretation. It needs a hard and fast indicator that identifies the contents of the cell as a comment paragraph or one of the other data types. What can you provide to help Excel identify the nature of the cell? If it needs a human being to do the classification, then you can't automate it with Excel.

Comment: As @teylyn  said! You need some indicators that can determine what is a comment, author's name etc. Up to you how you do it, but without it, we can't provide you with a code. Ideallly try to look for some common denominators or create a extra column where you'll choose this manually

Comment: To add to my comment above. This looks like something Excel is poor equipped to do and much more suited to a web-based language. Have you perhaps considered other alternatives? **This looks like something that could be much more easily handled through some API if it's an existing site, or just create a inter-liked SQL Database.** Do you absolutely need to store this data inside an excel sheet?

Comment: It might be possible to create a VBA or formula solution if you may provide some sample data. I suspect that we might be able to use your "Extraneous dash" field in order to get the like# and comments before that.

Comment: Yes @teylyn that's where where my mind was going. The number of likes could be used; it'd require me to add rows with the value 0 where no-one liked the comment but that's not too difficult. The dash appears after every comment and would be the best possibility for anchoring like that.

Comment: @Rawrplus I just added the link to the original post, they're copy-pasted (cringe) from a news site that manages comments with Disqus. I think they have an API but my coding knowledge is minimal. Searching for a solution that I understand how to use, like this one [link] (https://wiki.digitalmethods.net/Dmi/ToolDisqusScraper) didn't produce anything. Thanks!